# EntityFramework AddRange doesn't insert anythin

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to test addRange performance with following code:

```
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Unit EfPerformanceTests")]
    public async Task EfPerformanceGlobal_AddRangeInsertFor10000Rows_SaveToDatabase()
    {
        var rowAmountPre = await _unit.Repository<PaymentProvider>().Queryable().ToListAsync();
        var rowAmountToInsert = 10000;

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        var paymentProviders = new List<PaymentProvider>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rowAmountToInsert; ++i)
        {
            var paymentProvider = new PaymentProvider
            {
                Label = "Provider Name"
            };

            paymentProviders.Add(paymentProvider);
        }


        _unit.Repository<PaymentProvider>().InsertGraphRange(paymentProviders);
        await _unit.SaveChangesAsync();

        stopwatch.Stop();

        var filePath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\EfPerformanceTests.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, "AddRangeInsert(rows " + rowAmountToInsert + "): " + stopwatch.Elapsed);

        var rowAmountPost = await _unit.Repository<PaymentProvider>().Queryable().ToListAsync();

        Assert.AreEqual(rowAmountPre.Count + rowAmountToInsert, rowAmountPost.Count);
    }
```

Database threw exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Saving or accepting changes failed
>   because more than one entity of type
>   'App.Model.Context.PaymentProvider' have the same primary key value.
>   Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that
>   database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the
>   database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer
>   for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the
>   'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or
>   'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.

I am not sure why EF recognizes same primary key value for entities, when auto increment is set up in db table.

Edit PaymentProvider entity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Repository.Pattern.Ef6;
using LocationApp.Model.Context;

public partial class PaymentProvider : Entity, IPaymentProvider
{
    public PaymentProvider()
    {
        this.LogPayments = new HashSet<LogPayment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LogPayment> LogPayments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: show code for `PaymentProvider`. The exception also states some steps you can take to fix problem. have you tried any of them.

Comment: I am using DB First/Model first, yes primary key was checked.

Comment: in your `.edmx` (Entity design) make sure the `Id` for `Paymentprovider` has `Entity Key` as `true` and also that `StoreGeneratedPattern` is set to `Identity`

Comment: It's not a database error, it's still in C# code. EF thinks you're trying to insert PaymentProviders with identical primary key values (`0`) because you didn't tell it that the database generates the new values, see Nkosi's comment.

Comment: It is set already in edmx of course. Please view following image: http://puu.sh/nW1bq/c6565b1577.png

Comment: OK, so what happens in `InsertGraphRange`?